# Object has no method 'call' when setting Backbone Model from Trigger

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

So, I just spent about 3 hours trying to debug this nasty thing and I'm at wits end.

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple. I'm working with a search query (string) and trying to set a global model with its attributes. However, when I'm moving to a different view, I want the model to clear out these attributes, or of course when they enter a new search query, have the event fire again.  I'm trying to use the Backbone Marionette Wreqr / Event Aggregator to manage the events here.

I don't know if it's because I'm using requirejs, or not scoping things correctly, but I'm hitting this very confusing error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'call' backbone.amd.min.js:1
f backbone.amd.min.js:1
e.Events.trigger backbone.amd.min.js:1
i.extend.set backbone.amd.min.js:1
(anonymous function) app.js:42
f backbone.amd.min.js:1
e.Events.trigger backbone.amd.min.js:1
Application.searchRoute app.js:81
(anonymous function) backbone.amd.min.js:1
(anonymous function) backbone.amd.min.js:1
w.some.w.any underscore.amd.min.js:1
i.extend.loadUrl backbone.amd.min.js:1
i.extend.navigate backbone.amd.min.js:1
i.extend.navigate backbone.amd.min.js:1
SidebarLayout.search sidebar.js:177
(anonymous function) sidebar.js:3
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
y.handle
```

And here's some of my application code (my main controller). As you can see, I'm trying to set up the app.searchResult model with these other parameters from the `searchRoute` method.

What's so bizarre is that it works the first time the page loads, but when I attempt to use router navigate or do anything but refresh the page, it fails.

I tried using `@searchResult` instead, tried adding a `, @` after my trigger call, and all sorts of other things. What's stranger is that inside that scope, `app.searchResult` is available to me. And as soon as I remove the `set` call from there, the error doesn't happen anymore, so I'm thinking it *must* be that?

```
define [
  'backbone.marionette',
  'global/layouts/home',
  'global/layouts/layout',
  'search/models/search-results',
  'search/collections/panels',
  'global/collections/categories',
  'global/collections/stores',
  'global/collections/searchResults',
  'search/views/panels',
  'apps/router'
], (Marionette, homeLayout, subpageLayout, SearchResultModel, PanelsCollection, CategoriesCollection, StoresCollection, SearchResultsCollection, PanelsView, Router) ->

  class Application extends Backbone.Marionette.Application

    onInitializeAfter: =>

      # Main Region
      @addRegions
        mainRegion: '#app'

      # AppRouter
      @router = new Router controller: @

      # Request Response / Vent
      @reqRes()
      @appVent()

      # Global Search Result Model
      @searchResult = new SearchResultModel()

      Backbone.history.start
        pushState:  false
        root:       ""

    searchRoute: (query, params) ->

      params = $.extend params, text: query
      @vent.trigger "search:setParams", params

      @subpageLayout = new subpageLayout()
      @mainRegion.show @subpageLayout

    appVent: ->
      @vent.on "search:setParams", (params) ->
        app.searchResult.set("params", params)
      @vent.on "sidebar:reset", ->
        app.searchResult.set("params", null)
```

I can send more code if you like, but the idea is to use a custom trigger like `sidebar:reset` to clear out these parameters. I'm also listening to some model events (all of that stuff is working great from within the context of the view and when I don't mess with the event aggregator).

Thanks in advance for your help. You have no idea how many hours I just spent on this!

Comment: So I kind of figured out what was going on. It had to do with event listeners and context. I'm still a bit confused because I had to do this to get it to work:

`searchResult.listenTo @, "change:params", @setSidebarContent(), @`

Comment: Note you probably want `@setSidebarContent` instead of `@setSidebarContent()` (i.e. passing a reference to a function instead of the result provided by the function call).

Comment: @DavidSulc so is the rest of that code okay to you? Is this how you would handle vent triggers directly on the view?